# Optimize PHP Script for insert in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this situation:

- more than 2000 file with fix structure;
- any file have approximately 200.000 row
- for me every single line is a document MongoDB (200.000 document per file)

so, I open a file with php and insert any single document in MongoDB. 
Then the script insert approximately 400.000.000 of Document.

My script use 5hours for insert approximately 60 file (12.000.000 document).

My question is:
Is possible optimize the script for reduce the time of insert?

PS: 
I remove the index in MongoDB for more fast insert;
I work in local with Wamp

SCRIPT:

```
<?php
    // connect to mongodb
    $m = new MongoClient();
    function spacePosition($stringa){
        $pos=0;
        //substr(string,start,length) 
        $lunghezzaStringa = strlen($stringa);
        while($pos<$lunghezzaStringa){

            if(substr($stringa,$pos,1)==" ") {
                return $pos;
            } else {
                $pos=$pos+1;
            }

        }

    }

    //Funzione per inserire un Documento BED in MongoDB
    function insertDocumentBed($document,&$m){
        // select a database
        $db = $m->BRCA;
        $collection = $db->bedCollection;
        unset($document->_id);
        $collection->insert($document);
    }

    //Fine Funzione per inserire un Documento BED in MongoDB
    $directory = "D:/other/BRCA/dnamethylationTemp";
    $tumor="BRCA";
    $experiment="dnamethylation";

    if (is_dir($directory)) {

        if ($directory_handle = opendir($directory)) {
            while (($file = readdir($directory_handle)) !== false) {

                if((!is_dir($file))&($file!=".")&($file!=".."))                                                        $extension = pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                if(trim($extension)=="meta"){
                    //...//                     
                }

                //FINE ESTRAZIONE DATI DA FILE .META
            }

            elseif(trim($extension)=="bed"){
                ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
                //0=NOLIMIT
                $nuovaDirectory = $directory."/".$file;
                $handle = fopen($nuovaDirectory, "r");
                $filename = basename($nuovaDirectory);
                $patient_id = substr($filename,0,12);
                $document1 = array('filename'=>$filename);
                //init

                if ($handle) {
                    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                        $row = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$line);
                        $rowSplit = explode(" ", $row);
                        $chrom = $rowSplit[0];
                        $chromStart = $rowSplit[1];
                        $chromEnd = $rowSplit[2];
                        $strand = $rowSplit[3];
                        $composite_element_ref = $rowSplit[4];
                        $beta_value = $rowSplit[5];
                        $gene_symbol = $rowSplit[6];
                        $document1["tumor"] = $tumor;
                        $document1["experiment"] = $experiment;
                        $document1["PATIENT_ID"] = $patient_id;
                        $document1["filename"] = $filename;
                        $document1["chrom"] = $chrom;
                        $document1["chromStart"] = (int)$chromStart;
                        $document1["chromEnd"] = (int)$chromEnd;
                        $document1["strand"] = $strand;
                        $document1["composite_element_ref"] = $composite_element_ref;
                        $document1["beta_value"] = (float)$beta_value;
                        $document1["gene_symbol"] = $gene_symbol;
                        insertDocumentBed($document1,$m);
                    }

                    fclose($handle);
                } else {
                    // error opening the file.
                }

                //
                //Fine Estrazione da File .BED
            }

        }

        closedir($directory_handle);
    }

}

$m->close();
?>
```

Comment: Which section of your script is the slow part? I see a `preg_replace()` and regex is notorious for making things slow.

Comment: Also, you have too many closing braces `}` so your script should be failing anyways...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus sorry for the } i cut piece of code , the script work. if is possible attache the php file i resolve

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thank's for preg_replace , there is a more efficient function?

Comment: Any help please ?

Comment: Try batch Insert in mongodb for more detail URL: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php

Comment: @IndrajeetSingh Thanks I try and upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Batch Insert in mongodb for more detail for [Click Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php)

Comment: I substitute Insert with BatchInsert but i obtain this error : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'No write ops were  included in the batch'